# zbar #ifdef issue with minizip in iOS

Tags: ios, zip, conditional-compilation, zbar-sdk

i need to write the #import "ZBarSDK.h" into the #ifdef **OBJ** part, because Minizip does not work if there's an import at another place!

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ZBarSDK.h"
#endif
```

but then i get an error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZBarReaderViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_ZBarReaderControllerResults", referenced from:
      -[ViewController imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:] in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CIImage", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ImageViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

anyone can help?
myr0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two messages' reason may be that the 'ZBarSDK' provides a static library (ZBarSDK.a) that contains ARMv6 code (or maybe Intel i386) only. You either need to download a more recent version that provides ARMv7 object code, or download its source code and compile it for yourself.

The 3rd error comes from the fact that you haven't added the CoreImage framework to your project.

Comment: CoreImages right! The other one was missing libzbar.a! This has nothing to do with #ifdef... anyway, thanks!